# Zend Framework View Helper: Where does this method come from?

Tags: zend-framework

I have a Zend view template with the following line of code:

```
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ')
```

My question is, where is the setSeparator() method declared?

I understand that headTitle is a View Helper but when I look in the Zend_View_Helper_HeadTitle class I see no setSeparator method, nor any setter.  Presumably the method (or an appropriate setter) is declared in the class' ancestors however I can't seem to find exactly where...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defined in `Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Abstract`.
The access to this method takes place in `Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Standalone` class in its magic method `__call` :

```
$container = $this->getContainer();
if (method_exists($container, $method)) {
    $return = call_user_func_array(array($container, $method), $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is defined using PHP [magic method __set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).  The magic method is defined in the Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Standalone class which is the base class for Zend_View_Helper_HeadLink.